# Video server for LAN (headless) with RTP and DLNA?

Tags: linux, video, streaming, dlna

[`VideoLAN`](http://www.videolan.org/) does not support DLNA and doesn't wish to, and servers like [`Plex`](https://plex.tv/) do not support RTP and do not wish to.

Also, I have various devices at home, which are all hard-nosed in similar way.

So I think this is server who should be multi-protocol.

So, the question is: what is this server?

OS is Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking about supporting both DLNA from my RTSP project @
net7mma - Managed Media Aggregation [archived by Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813023018/https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=net7mma) or [Github Repository](https://github.com/juliusfriedman/net7mma) but until then...

Just use VideoLan to output to a pipe, then use any DLNA Server to read the pipe with meta information created from the SDP of the RTP/RTSP/RTMP/HTTP/ETC stream. This will effectively create a virtual DLNA item with the output from VideoLan.

See also [Implementing a DLNA-compliant UPnP AV MediaServer with DVB and RTSP/RTP support - Martin Emrich (Bachelor’s Thesis)](https://web.archive.org/web/20180127033925/http://www.nt.uni-saarland.de/fileadmin/file_uploads/theses/bachelor/bachelor-thesis-final_01.pdf)

See also [SimpleDLNA](https://github.com/nmaier/simpleDLNA/)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are searching for minidnla https://sourceforge.net/projects/minidlna/ (Now is called ReadyMedia)

you can install on ubuntu using `apt-get install minidnla`